# query table plugin which has capability of subtotals

Tags: jquery-ui, jquery-plugins, jquery

Is there a plugin which has the capability of subtotals for JQuery?
I did search around, I found a list of all table plugins for JQuery
But was unable to find ones which have the subtotal capabilities.

Thanks
Mark

Answer (score 1):

you can use the **grouping ability** of the plugins to design subtotals:

- see [here](http://www.datatables.net/release-datatables/extras/FixedColumns/row_grouping.html) or [here](http://www.datatables.net/release-datatables/extras/FixedColumns/row_grouping.html) for [Datatables](http://www.datatables.net)
- see [here](http://www.trirand.com/jqgridwiki/doku.php?id=wiki%3agrouping) for jqgrid